# Animating centered inline block elements

Tags: html, css, css-animations

Is there any way how to animate centered inline block elements using pure CSS? What I'am trying to do is to animate alignment of `<li>` elements inside of `<ul>` when adding (or removing) list items. Have a look at my [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qgqw3ceq/), when new item is added, other previous items jumps slightly to left to remain center-aligned. What I wish to do is to animate that jump to be smooth.

```
div.wrap {
  width: 330px;
  text-align: center;
}

ul#list {
  margin: 0;
}

ul#list > li {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 3px solid blue;
  list-style-type: none;
}
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "animate alignment of `<li>`"? i.e. from what to what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the **`newItem`** itself can be animated ***in*** (or an **`oldItem`** can be animated ***out***) using CSS **[animation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_CSS_animations)** property with the help of a little bit of JavaScript (yes, you still need it).

But animating the re-adjustment of the other items, based on any of the scenarios mentioned above, is a bit complicated.

Anyway, take a look at **[this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tahirahmed/8jyLLqzs/)** as a demonstration.

***Snippet:***

```js
function addItem(list, newItem) {
    newItem.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeEnd', 'X');
    list.appendChild(newItem);
    newItem.classList.add('animatein');
}

function removeItem(list){
    var oldItem = null;
    if (list.childNodes.length > 0){
        oldItem = list.childNodes[list.childNodes.length - 1];
        oldItem.classList.remove('animatein');
        oldItem.classList.add('animateout');
        oldItem.addEventListener('animationend', function(){
            list.removeChild(oldItem);
        });
    }
}

var list = document.getElementById('list');
var newItem = document.createElement('li');

var button = document.getElementById('add');
var removeButton = document.getElementById('remove');
button.addEventListener('click', function () {
    addItem(list, newItem.cloneNode());
});
removeButton.addEventListener('click', function(){
    removeItem(list);
});
```

```css
div.wrap {
    width: 330px;
    text-align: center;
}
ul#list {
    margin: 0;
}
ul#list > li {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    border: 3px solid blue;
    list-style-type: none;
}

.animatein { animation: .4s fadein; }
.animateout { animation: .4s fadeout; }

@keyframes fadein {
    from { opacity: 0; left: 100px; }
    to { opacity: 1; left: 0px; }
}

@keyframes fadeout {
    from { opacity: 1; left: 0px; }
    to { opacity: 0; left: 100px; }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
    <ul id="list"></ul>
</div>
<button id="add">Add</button>
<button id="remove">Remove</button>
```

Is this what you were looking for? Hope this helps in some way.

Comment: Somehow I managed to make it. Unfortunately, there has to be lot of JS, which I hoped to avoid [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/k9tfzr4y/1/).

Comment: @HonzaStrouhal: Ah I see. As I had mentioned, re-adjustment of other items was deemed to be a little more complicated. But it was not very apparent in your question that you wanted to: **(a)** make them all appear in one row and **(b)** re-adjust the whole list and the re-adjust items upon addition of a new list-item or removal of the last list-item. Anyway, cool solution. Glad you found a way around.

Comment: you know, this is my first question on stackoverflow ever :) anyway many thanks for your will to help

Comment: Don't worry about it. Happens to all of us. :)